# something strange when using icmp->getOpcode() function

Tags: llvm

I tried to use following codes to get the opcode of icmp instruction,

```
int opCode = icmp -> getOpcode();
```

when I run the statement on an icmp instruction likes this

```
%cmp = icmp eq i32 %0, 0
```

however, I got the opCode is '52', but actually, for operation 'eq' ,opCode should be '32',

```
ICMP_EQ    = 32,  ///< equal
```

why this strange phenomenon occurs ? and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may knew how to solve this problem, getCode() will return an error code, so we can use getPredicate() to replace it.